# Intellij: Expression of type IO[Long] doesn't conform to expected type FS2_[O2_]

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, fs2, cats-effect

I tried the code of this Blog: [a-streaming-library-with-a-superpower-fs2-and-functional-programming](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-streaming-library-with-a-superpower-fs2-and-functional-programming-6f602079f70a)

In **Intellij** this code:

```
Stream("bob", "alice", "joe")
      .evalMap(name => IO.fromFuture(IO(loadUserIdByName(name)))) // <- here is the exception
      .compile
      .toList
```

Gives me this exception:

```
Expression of type IO[Long] doesn't conform to expected type FS2_[O2_]
```

Running the code with `sbt` works without a problem.

Is there a way to get rid of this exception in **Intellij**?

Comment: you could help by setting the type yourself; `evalMap[IO, Long]`

Comment: @Raf thanks that worked! - can you create an answer, so  I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed myself the typechecker always needs some help here, so explicitly set the effect and return type: in your case `evalMap[IO, Long]`